# valid array testing and loops

Tags: php, performance

I have a lot of arrays to test , is there a better to way in term of performance on doing the following :

```
if(is_array($data) && count($data) > 0) {

           foreach($data as $d) {

           }  
  }
```

can this code be better ?

Comment: so you want to iterate through the whole array and still want complexity less than O(n)

Comment: what happens after `foreach`

Comment: i process the data inside the loop :  $tmp[] = $this->processData($d);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine to me, but i would rather use `empty` then do a `count()`:

```
if(is_array($data) && !empty($data))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really that unsure whether `$data` really contains an array? If you do proper programming `$data` should not magically be an array one time and something else another time.

Additionally you cannot only loop over arrays, but as well over objects that implement `Iterator`.

After doing some tests by myself `is_array` seems to be the fastest way to check (at least on my computer `PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1 (cli)`) I know. The only other way to to the check I know of is: `(array) $data === $data` and this is slower than `is_array`

Comment: No i can't trust the system , and don't want to have an error if it happens and the $data is not an array .. that's why i have to check .